# MySQL timestamp не удается записать информацию timezone

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, timestamp

До сегодняшнего момента я полагал что `TIMESTAMP` в `MySQL` должен содержать информацию о `timezone`
Но столкнувшись с темой на практике получил следующее

```sql
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR , '2020-12-22T04:10:45+00:00', '2020-12-22T04:10:45+03:00');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR , '2020-12-22T04:10:45+00:00', '2020-12-22T04:10:45+03:00') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             -3 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Кроме того. Делая попытку записать данные из python получаю ситуацию тоже свидетельствующую о том, что либо я не понимаю как это должно работать (что вероятнее всего) либо я что-то не так настроил:

```py
from common.mysql_connection import db_connection
    from datetime import datetime
    import pytz

    call_datetime: datetime = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.fromisoformat('2020-12-22 04:10:45'))

    in_server = call_datetime.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))

    print(call_datetime, in_server)

    db_connection.cursor.executemany(
        "insert into infinity.calls (row_id, trigger_datetime) values (%s, %s);", [
            [
                126356,
                in_server
            ],
            [
                5858585,
                call_datetime
            ]
        ]
    )
# 2020-12-22 04:10:45+00:00 2020-12-22 07:10:45+03:00
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Собственно вопрос. Можно ли (и нужно ли) сделать так чтобы было
> `2020-12-22 04:10:45+00:00 == 2020-12-22 07:10:45+03:00`

Привести все значения времени в коде к часовому поясу сервера это не проблема. Я просто не понимаю как это правильно должно выглядеть и работать в MySQL

**UPD**

```sql
insert into test (
                  ts, # timestamp
                  dt  # datetime
                  )
values ('2020-12-22 04:10:45+03:00', '2020-12-22 04:10:45+00:00'),
       ('2020-12-22 04:10:45+03:00', '2020-12-22 04:10:45+00:00');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте тип DATETIME

Из документации mysql

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
> storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
> (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)

Comment: И что мне это даст? не совсем понимаю.

Comment: Ну собственно да. Затупил

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp не зависит от часового пояса ([в UNIX, по крайней мере](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). Это количество секунд от "абсолютного момента времени", полуночи 1 января 1970 года по всемирному координированному времени, UTC (время по Гринвичу без поправок на летнее время). Другими словами, независимо от вашего часового пояса, timestamp представляет момент, который везде одинаков.